# Using jsSIP in A Project

Tags: webrtc, sip, jssip

We're using jsSIP in our project and I'm trying to get phone number of the caller when receiving an incoming call. I could't find the answer in the jsSIP [documentation](http://jssip.net/documentation/).

[image]

In the above image, i want to take "1004" telephone number. How can i do that?

Comment: When you receive the 'newRTCSession' event in JsSIP there is a session object including the remote identity.

Comment: Hey @gustavogb do you have a example project like that?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use

```
session.remote_identity.display_name
```

for incoming calls

Answer (score 2):

You can try this for incoming and outgoing calls and you will get the user that is calling you or you are calling

```
session.remote_identity.uri.user
```

You can try this for incoming and outgoing calls and you will get the user call-id name

```
session.remote_identity.display_name
```

Answer (score 1):

In `newRTCSession` Event you will get a session object. 
`session.request.header`.

Use `session.request.getHeader('From')` to get From number

```
coolPhone.on('newRTCSession',function(session){
   console.log(session.request);
   console.log('call Id',session.request.getHeader('From'));
})
```